# How can I change the style of a component when its parent is hovered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, sass

So I am using sass/scss and I need to change the style of a component when its parent is hovered.

```
<Card className="choose-profile-card"
      onClick={() => this.handleChangeCardSelection('investor')}>
   <div className="btn-flat--within" />
</Card>
```

And I mean to do something like:

```
.choose-profile-card {
    &:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

      .btn-flat--within {
         background-color: red;
      }
    }
}
```

Got it? That's the idea, when `.choose-profile-card` is hovered, I need to change the style of `.btn-flat--within`, is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is the resulting html from your JSX?  Are you sure that the className is getting propagated through to the render.  Because if so the CSS looks correct...

Comment: Show the rendered HTML here perhaps.  Also changing the background color of an element that has no size is unlikely to show up visually. So, what else gives it size, anything? some library CSS?  And does THAT override here?

Answer (score 0):

It should work as is. The issue may be because the `<div className="btn-flat--within" />` has no content in it. try `<div className="btn-flat--within" >some text</div>` or adding a height to the `btn-flat--within` class

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1uz0sah/